# How to save Strings?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-studio, instance

I'm programming a simple app that has two Activities.  I can switch to an Activity by clicking on an item in the OptionMenu.

Now, I want to save the instance.  When I write something in an EditText in Activity 1 and change to Activity 2 and then switch back again to Activity 1, I want the data (String) to be restored in the EditText.

How can I do this?

This is the code for Activity 1:

```
public class ActivityA extends Activity {

private String txt1;
private String txt2;
private String txt3;
private String txt4;

private EditText edText1;
private EditText edText2;
private EditText edText3;
private EditText edText4;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);  
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_a); 
    setTitle(R.string.activity1_title);  

    txt1 = "-";
    txt2 = "-";
    txt3 = "-";
    txt4 = "-";

    if (savedInstanceState != null){
        txt1 = savedInstanceState.getString("Value1");
        txt2 = savedInstanceState.getString("Value2");
        txt3 = savedInstanceState.getString("Value3");
        txt4 = savedInstanceState.getString("Value4");
    }

    edText1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
    edText1.setText(""+txt1);

    edText2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
    edText2.setText(""+txt2);

    edText3 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText3);
    edText3.setText(""+txt3);

    edText4 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText4);
    edText4.setText(""+txt4);
}

public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    savedInstanceState.putString("Value1",txt1);
    savedInstanceState.putString("Value2",txt2);
    savedInstanceState.putString("Value3",txt3);
    savedInstanceState.putString("Value4",txt4);

}

public void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    txt1 = savedInstanceState.getString("Value1");
    txt2 = savedInstanceState.getString("Value2");
    txt3 = savedInstanceState.getString("Value3");
    txt4 = savedInstanceState.getString("Value4");

}
}
```

The problem is that it doesn't save the strings, and I don't know why.
Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_shared_preferences.htm

Comment: this idea might be stupid - write to file to save string.!Sorry i'm new and I just got that idea .

Answer (score 1):

The super call `super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);` has to be called after the put statements

```
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    savedInstanceState.putString("Value1",edText1.getText().toString());
    savedInstanceState.putString("Value2",edText2.getText().toString());
    savedInstanceState.putString("Value3",edText3.getText().toString());
    savedInstanceState.putString("Value4",edText4.getText().toString());
    super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
}


public void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    txt1 = savedInstanceState.getString("Value1");
    edText1.setText(""+txt1);
    ....

}
```

Addition:

It is also pretty nice to use final variables for the Bundle Keys. (maybe static)

Comment: I Updated my answer. txt1 is "-" cause you don't update this value. get the text from the editView

Comment: Now I get an Error: Unknown hax vcpu return 1

Comment: @MomoSaibak thats a Emulator bug, which has nothing to do with this. I'm sure you'll find a way how to fix it on google. Otherwise use a real device.

Answer (score 1):

Shared preferences is the way to go for storing and retrieving simple data. Store it when you leave the first activity, and restore it in the onCreate when the user returns to the activity.

Answer (score 0):

You were almost right.
Just change the place of your super call and it should solve your issue.

```
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    savedInstanceState.putString("Value1",txt1);
    savedInstanceState.putString("Value2",txt2);
    savedInstanceState.putString("Value3",txt3);
    savedInstanceState.putString("Value4",txt4);
    super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);  // Call at the end
}

public void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);  // Call at the beginning
    txt1 = savedInstanceState.getString("Value1");
    txt2 = savedInstanceState.getString("Value2");
    txt3 = savedInstanceState.getString("Value3");
    txt4 = savedInstanceState.getString("Value4");
}
```

Comment: `super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);` Should be called first so the superclass get the bundle first. This way you make sure the child does not mess anythinbg up.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your code, I don't think your `onRestoreInstanceState` function will be called if you just come back from the second activity. I would recommend using Shared Preferences instead.

Because `onRestoreInstanceState` will be called only if:

1. You have savedInstanceState
2. Your activity has been killed by the system, and now it needs to recreate it.

Plus, you need to call `super.onSaveInstanceState()` function after you put all the saves in the bundle.